# reverses in arraylist strings

Tags: java

I am trying to reverse some contents of strings in an arraylist , and I was wondering if this was possible using standard classes [.reverse().toString() in particular]. For example, I have an arraylist with the following entries in them:

```
    mySuperArray=[the cost of apple is USD2, the cost of oranges are USD1.50]
```

and what Id want is something which reverses these strings in the above array: like:

```
    hArray=[2DSU si elppa fo tsoc eht, etc..]
```

What I am using at the moment is something like:

```
    ArrayList<String> hArray= new ArrayList<String>();
    hArray = new StringBuffer(mySuperArray).reverse().toString();
```

where, mySuperArray is defined the same way as hArray.

But I get a compile error at this stage:

```
    cannot find symbol
    symbol  : constructor StringBuffer(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)
    location: class java.lang.StringBuffer
    hArray = new StringBuffer(mySuperArray).reverse().toString();
```

Why do I get this compile error? What could be wrong?
Sorry if the question is a rather newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you cannot use a constructor StringBuffer(ArrayList). You can refer to the Java documentation online to see what constructors you can use. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html (this is Java 1.5). So, the closest constructor you can use is StringBuffer(String).

```
ArrayList hArray= new ArrayList();
for(String s :mySuperArray){
   hArray.add(new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString());
}
```

Comment: Ooh.. this is basically doing what Dave Newton said. :)

Comment: Thanks for this Neo. That basically explains it. However, when I do this, I get a weird compile error saying "file.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details." I have never seen this error before, and a basic google search does not seem to reveal a lot. Any ideas why I am getting this compile error?

Comment: OK I got it. Basically need to define that the array was of string type i.e <String> Thanks a lot Neo and Dave Newton!

Comment: It's only a WARNING.. not an error. You can choose to ignore it. Your program should still run. But to get rid of this one, you can use ArrayList<String> hArray = new ArrayList<String>(); instead of the one given above. It basically tells the java compiler that it should expect Strings as objects in the ArrayList.

Comment: If you are still getting such warnings, you need to edit all ArrayList constructors in your program.

Comment: Thanks Neo again for this. I got it. I put in the type and everything works like a charm now. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

There is no StringBuffer constructor that takes an ArrayList--what would it mean?

Create a new list, iterate over the original, adding the reverse of each string to the new list. Alternatively, replace each list item with its reverse. (Not as "functional".)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException, InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
        obj.add("A");
        obj.add("B");
        obj.add("C");
        obj.add("D");
        obj.add("E");
        System.out.println("Entered :: "+obj);
        for(int i=obj.size()-1; i>=0; --i){
            System.out.println("Values :: "+obj.get(i));
            obj.add(obj.get(i));
            obj.remove(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Reversed :: "+obj);
}
```